# how to create archive file by libarchive

Tags: c++, windows, libarchive

I use libarchive to create a archive, and the source is a directory, I need create the archive with the same directory tree of the source directory, so I use the archive_read_disk_open and archive_read_disk_descend, but when i create a file with archive_write_open_filename(a, "xxx.zip"),there is always only a "xxx" file in the result zip file, I have to extract the "xxx" file and then rename the "xxx" to "xxx.zip", then I get the correct zip file

If I read entry from the xxx.zip using libarchive, I can get the correct directory tree.

This is the C++ code I use to create the zip file:

```cpp
bool KArchiveManager::pack(const QString& srcDirPath)
{
    struct archive* a;
    struct archive_entry* entry;
    int r;

    a = archive_write_new();
    archive_write_set_format_zip(a);
    archive_write_set_compression_compress(a);
    QString outPath= srcDirPath + ".zip";
    
    r = archive_write_open_filename_w(a, outPath.toStdWString().c_str());
    if (r != ARCHIVE_OK)
    {
        QString msg = QString("archive_write_open_filename_w : %1")
            .arg(archive_error_string(a));
        emit packArchiveError(msg);
        archive_write_close(a);
        archive_write_free(a);
        return false;
    }

    QDir compressDir(srcDirPath);
    if (!compressDir.exists())
    {
        emit packArchiveError(tr("compress dir not exist"));
        archive_write_close(a);
        archive_write_free(a);
        return false;
    }

    QStringList entryList = compressDir.entryList(
        QDir::Dirs | QDir::Files | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
    foreach(const QString & entryName, entryList)
    {
        struct archive* disk = archive_read_disk_new();
        archive_read_disk_set_standard_lookup(disk);
        QString diskPath = compressDir.absoluteFilePath(entryName);
        r = archive_read_disk_open(disk, diskPath.toStdString().c_str());
        if (r != ARCHIVE_OK)
        {
            QString msg = QString("archive_read_disk_open : %1")
                .arg(archive_error_string(disk));
            emit packArchiveError(msg);
            archive_write_close(a);
            archive_write_free(a);
            archive_read_close(disk);
            archive_read_free(disk);
            return false;
        }

        while (true)
        {
            entry = archive_entry_new();
            r = archive_read_next_header(disk, &entry);
            if (r == ARCHIVE_EOF)
                break;
            if (r != ARCHIVE_OK)
            {
                QString msg = QString("archive_read_next_header : %1")
                    .arg(archive_error_string(disk));
                emit packArchiveError(msg);
                archive_write_close(a);
                archive_write_free(a);
                archive_read_close(disk);
                archive_read_free(disk);
                return false;
            }
            archive_read_disk_descend(disk);
            QString sourcePath = archive_entry_pathname(entry);
            QString pathName = sourcePath.mid(srcDirPath.size() + 1);
            archive_entry_set_pathname(entry, pathName.toLocal8Bit());
            r = archive_write_header(a, entry);
            if (r != ARCHIVE_OK)
            {
                QString msg = QString("archive_write_header : %1")
                    .arg(archive_error_string(a));
                emit packArchiveError(msg);
                archive_write_close(a);
                archive_write_free(a);
                archive_read_close(disk);
                archive_read_free(disk);
                return false;
            }
            //copydata
            if (archive_entry_filetype(entry) != AE_IFDIR)
            {
                QFile file(sourcePath);
                if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
                {
                    QDataStream in(&file);
                    while (!in.atEnd())
                    {
                        QByteArray chunk = file.read(1024);
                        archive_write_data(a, chunk.data(), chunk.size());
                    }
                    file.close();
                }
            }

            archive_entry_free(entry);
        }
        archive_read_close(disk);
        archive_read_free(disk);
    }
    archive_write_close(a);
    archive_write_free(a);
    return true;
}
```

How can I create the correct zip file instead of a zip file always contain the same name file of the param passed to the archive_write_open_filename?

Comment: You seem to view the file name in the Windows File Explorer that hides files extensions of known file types. The issue is not in libarchive.

Answer (score 0):

Run`cmd.exe`, within that use the `cd` command to navigate to the correct directory, then run the `dir` command, and check the filename in the output. It will be `xxx.zip`.

Some file managers such as Explorer hide the extension (`.zip` in this case). You can configure them to show the extension.

Comment: I am sorry, that's not the problem. I mean I create the xxx.zip, but there is not a directory tree in the xxx.zip, In the xxx.zip there is only one xxx file. I have to extract the xxx file,and then rename the xxx file to xxx.zip, then I can get the correct directory tree in the new xxx.zip

Comment: Please add the C++ code you use to create `xxx.zip`, and please upload and post a link to the `xxx.zip` created.

Comment: I have add the code I use but I dont know how to add the xxx.zip, this code can create a xxx.zip but when I open or extract this file  by WinRAR, I can only get a xxx file. I have to rename this xxx file to xxx.zip, then open or extract it again, in this way I can get the correct directory tree

Comment: but if I read entry from the xxx.zip by libarchive, I can get the correct directory tree

Comment: You can upload the xxx.zip file to Google Drive or some other site like fastupload.io. Without your xxx.zip file it's hard to give any meaningful advice.